# How to findall() a sequence of regular expressions to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am extracting some patterns with pandas [findall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) function. However, I have several regular expressions. This, how can I `findall` `N` regular expressions with pandas?.

For example, lets say that I would like to extract the all the numbers and all the dates inside an specific column:

In:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': ['This dataset 11/12/98 contains 5,000 rows, which were sampled from a 500,000 11/12/12 row dataset spanning the same time period. Throughout these analyses', 

                                'the number of events you count will be about 100 times smaller than they 11/12/78 actually were, but the 01/12/11 proportions of events will still generally be reflective that larger dataset. In this case, a sample is fine because our purpose is to learn methods of data analysis with Python, not to create 100% accurate recommendations to Watsi.']})

dfs
```

Out:

```
    c1
0   This dataset 11/12/98 contains 5,000 rows, whi...
1   the number of events you count will be about 1...
```

I tried to, but I am getting the following error:

In:

```
dfs['patterns'] = dfs['c1'].str.findall([r'\d+',r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)']).apply(', '.join)

dfs
```

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-af2969e06a61> in <module>()
----> 1 dfs['patterns'] = dfs['c1'].str.findall([r'\d+',r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)']).apply(', '.join)
      2 dfs

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in wrapper2(self, pat, flags, **kwargs)
   1268 
   1269     def wrapper2(self, pat, flags=0, **kwargs):
-> 1270         result = f(self._data, pat, flags=flags, **kwargs)
   1271         return self._wrap_result(result)
   1272 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in str_findall(arr, pat, flags)
    827     extractall : returns DataFrame with one column per capture group
    828     """
--> 829     regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
    830     return _na_map(regex.findall, arr)
    831 

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/re.py in compile(pattern, flags)
    222 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    223     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
--> 224     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    225 
    226 def purge():

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/re.py in _compile(pattern, flags)
    279     # internal: compile pattern
    280     try:
--> 281         p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
    282         if loc is None or loc == _locale.setlocale(_locale.LC_CTYPE):
    283             return p

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Therefore how can I "stack", "nest" or apply several regex with `findall` function?. **What I expect as an output is the resolution of each regular expression separated by `,` in a single column**:

```
   col
0  '11/12/98', '5', '000', '500', '000', '11/12/12'
1  '100', '11/12/78', '01/12/11', '100'
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to:

```
dfs['patterns'] = dfs['c1'].str.map(findall(),[r'\d+',r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)']).apply(', '.join)
dfs
```

Comment: what do you expect as an output?

Comment: I updated the question with the expected output @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not clear your desired output.
But please check below code.

```
dfs['patterns'] = dfs['c1'].str.findall(r'\d+\/\d+\/\d+|\d+')
print dfs['patterns'].sum()

['11/12/98', '5', '000', '500', '000', '11/12/12', '100', '11/12/78', '01/12/11', '100']
```

Comment: We can grab all of the numbers together with commas by adding a comma with a positive lookahead of a digit : `r'\d+\/\d+\/\d+|\d+\,?(?=\d)\d+'`.

Placing this regex into your code yields:
` ['11/12/98', '5,000', '500,000', '11/12/12', '100', '11/12/78', '01/12/11', '100']`

Assuming this is actually what the person is trying to do.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)  shows that the input pattern must be a single string so you cannot input multiple regular expressions. You must construct a single regular expression that includes all of the cases you wish to grab as is done in this answer.

Comment: I updated the question with more details about the output guys! @qRTPCR

Comment: In replying to your update, the above answer is the beginning of your solution. If you check out the `dfs['patterns']` column above (before calling sum on it) you'll see that you have a list in each row with the numbers you are trying to find. The next step is to join the list as you desire for each row. Here is one way to do this:

`dfs['c1'].str.findall(r'\d+\/\d+\/\d+|\d+').apply(lambda x : ', '.join(x))`
Edit : this is assuming you want each row to be a string instead of a list.

Comment: So, just with `|`?... I all ready try that but I am not getting all the patterns I wanna extract..

Comment: Yes that is the `or` operator that lets you chain together different regular expressions.